# remove vibration from notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-audiomanager, vibration

I want to disable vibrations for notifications but I am not able to make it work. I want to make the notification sound be heard, but the phone should not vibrate. Here is my code:

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 2, 0);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
```

but when I receive a message or other notification that uses default sound settings, the phone vibrates. Can someone tell me how to achieve my goal?

Comment: I have your same problem and I am not able to solve it. Where you? This is really a hole in Android programming (like many others)

Comment: @Ton No, I was not able to solve this

Comment: check if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008764/disable-vibration-for-a-notification may fix for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are not stop because you are use `"setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)"` in notification code so if you need to stop vibration and sound remove this line , or if you need to use the default sound and stop vibration I think you must use `setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)` etc ...

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should not be directly using `AudioManager`. Instead, use [`Notification` APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html):

```
if (isVibrationEnabled) {
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
}
```

Comment: does this works for notifications for other applications? I'm not making notifications, I just want to disable vibrations for all the notifications

Comment: You can't disable vibration for all apps notifications unless you set the device to silent mode (for that, use `audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);`). Although, there are apps which override the silent mode and use vibration (most of them follow user settings of course).

Comment: so I want to change this settings for notificationd and I know that these settings will work only for applications that follow user's settings. But I want the user to hear notification sount, but disable vibrations, but that code does not works, and I don't know why

Comment: Probably, because _"`setVibrateSetting()` --- **This method was deprecated in API level 16.** Applications should maintain their own vibrate policy based on current ringer mode that can be queried via getRingerMode()."_

Answer (score -1):

You will have to remove Vibration code form Notification api :

```
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Comment: He is not talking about his own notifications